# How to Ungroup (UnJoin) a Mesh

Tags: mesh

I Need to know how to Ungroup Meshes that were Previously joined Without Undoing History.

I Am attempting to ungroup things like [these](http://darkknightpl.deviantart.com/art/EverythingAnimations-FNaF-1-Models-for-Blender-568267642).
If you select anything on the models in there you will notice they are a big mesh made with the **CTRL J** Trick

I Need to know how to Ungroup it from that.

(Unless it can't be done. -_- and i have to try to recreate the meshes entirely)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Select your mesh
2. Enter edit mode
3. Select all vertices using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
4. Select mesh menu->Vertices->Separate->by loose parts or just Press <kbd>P</kbd> and choose by Loose Parts

This will separate your mesh into different meshes again.

Comment: Just in case, mesh menu = edit mode (click `Tab`)